# Looping background image in Ruby side-scrolling game

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I want to loop the background image in a Ruby gosu side scrolling game.I have problem with the counters `@k` and `@p` which are used to translate the background image and the duplicated background image.I can't think of a good way to plus them.Here's the code to make it more clear.

```
require 'gosu'

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
attr_accessor :x, :y

SHIFT = 700

 def initialize
  super 640,440
  @background  = Gosu::Image.new("./images/bg.png")
  @player      = Gosu::Image.new("./images/000.png")
  @x1, @y1 = 0, 0
  @player_x, @player_y = 50, 50
  @k = 0    #counter
  @p = 1    #counter
 end

 def update
  @x1 -= 3
  @player_y += 1 if @player_y <= 375
  @player_y -= 3 if button_down?(Gosu::KbSpace) and @player_y >= 0

  @coordinates = Gosu::Image.from_text(
    self, "#{@x1},#{@k}", Gosu.default_font_name, 30)
  #here should be the code for @k and @p
 end

 def draw
  @background.draw(@x1  + @k*SHIFT, @y1, 0)
  @background.draw(@x1 +  @p*SHIFT, @y1, 0)
  @player.draw(@player_x, @player_y, 0)
  @coordinates.draw(0, 0, 1)
 end

 def button_down(id)
  $window.close if id == Gosu::KbEscape
 end

end

window = GameWindow.new
window.show
```

So how do I plus the counters `@k` and `@p`.Tried this

```
if @x1 > -(SHIFT+5)*@p and @x1 < -SHIFT*@p  #705 and 700
  @k += 2
end

if @k > 0 and @x1 > -SHIFT*@k - 5 and @x1 < -SHIFT*@k - 3  #1405 and 1403
  @p += 2 
end
```

but it works only in the beginning(2-3 image shifts).
Also tried this

```
if @x1 == -SHIFT*@p
  @k += 2
end
```

and it did not work.

Comment: Okay, this looks overly complicated, and the generic variable names don't help. I'm going to try to detangle what you have and figure it out.

Comment: The "short answer" part of me wants to recommend that you use modulo operators (which you're not using right now) to calculate the offset/wrapping of the screen and just store a single horizontal offset, then take that in your `draw` step, calculate true image offsets there, and render the two backgrounds using those offsets.

Comment: Are you doing vertical scroll as well?

Comment: Also, do you need two `Gosu::Image` instances, or can you just call `draw` twice on the same one with different coordinates?

Comment: Only horizontal.Left to right.Thanks about the gosu::image instances.Did not know that.Gonna fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assumptions & Analysis

I'm assuming that `@x1` and `@y1` are the offset of the left-most background's origin relative to the screen. You also have `@player_x` and `@player_y`, which denote the player's position on the screen. Your player is kept horizontally in the center of the screen, moving vertically when jumping or falling, and your background only scrolls horizontally. Also, your window size is 640x440, and your background image is 700px wide and at least 440px tall.

Your `update` step handles things like jumping (but only to the top of the screen) and simple, constant-velocity gravity, both by modifying the player's screen coordinates. It also provides a constant horizontal scroll by subtracting 3 units per frame from `@x1`, the horizontal camera coordinate in world-space.

Your `draw` step then takes the background image and draws two of them, offsetting them by the camera offset `@x1` plus the shift for which image is which. **This shift, however, isn't important, because we can calculate it fairly simply, and we're left without having to manipulate the additional state of remembering which one is which.**

## Code Solution

Instead of remembering the counter values `@k` and `@p`, we're going to just modulo by the image width to eliminate the excess in `@x1` and get it where we need it to be. `@k` and `@p` are useless, so delete those. `SHIFT` can be deleted as well.

Instead, we need to do the following:

- Calculate the screen offset of the left-most image
- Determine if two images need to be drawn instead of just one
- Draw the image(s)

Our goal looks something like this:

[image: sliding background]

Our new code:

```
require 'gosu'

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
  attr_accessor :x, :y # side note - are these used at all?

  def initialize
    super 640,440
    @background  = Gosu::Image.new("./images/bg.png")
    @player      = Gosu::Image.new("./images/000.png")
    @x1, @y1 = 0, 0
    @player_x, @player_y = 50, 50
  end

  def update
    @x1 -= 3
    @player_y += 1 if @player_y <= 375
    @player_y -= 3 if button_down?(Gosu::KbSpace) and @player_y >= 0

    @coordinates = Gosu::Image.from_text(
      self, "#{@x1}", Gosu.default_font_name, 30)
  end

  def draw
    # the important bits!
    @local_x = @x1 % -@background.width
    @background.draw(@local_x, @y1, 0)
    @background.draw(@local_x + @background.width, @y1, 0) if @local_x < (@background.width - self.width)

    @player.draw(@player_x, @player_y, 0)
    @coordinates.draw(0, 0, 1)
  end

  def button_down(id) # Side note: Does this work correctly?
    $window.close if id == Gosu::KbEscape
  end

end

window = GameWindow.new
window.show
```

What this does is, it takes `@x1` and *modulos* it with the (negative) width of the image. This means, it gives the remainder of an integer division of the two numbers. Modulo is very useful when trying to ensure that an integer value "wraps around" after exceeding a limit in either direction; it effectively maps it to between 0 (inclusive) and the given number (exclusive). The results of this are illustrated in the graphic above.

Keep in mind this solution only works as-is for your circumstances; vertical scrolling will require more code, and this will break pretty quickly if your window becomes wider than your background image.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.Thank you!